# mongodb - exclude subdocument depending on $gte while still returning root document

Tags: mongodb

I would like to only return a subdocument if its expire field is in the future. My problem is that I would like to get the root document anyway.

I am currently using:

```
sub.expire: {"$gte": now}
```

it only returns the root document if sub.expire is true.

how would I return the root document regardless if sub gets returned or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't quite how MongoDB is designed.  You're phrasing it as, you're trying to query a bunch of subdocuments and return them conditionally while returning the parent documents unconditionally; but as far as MongoDB is concerned there isn't a collection of subdocuments, there's a collection of documents, which each have fields, some of which may be subdocuments.  When you say you're "using" this condition on a subdocument -- presumably for find() -- what you're really asking the collection for is documents which satisfy this condition in a subdocument.  So documents that *don't* satisfy that condition aren't returned.

From MongoDB's point of view, what you actually want is closer to, return every document in the collection, but with a certain field (a subdocument, as it happens) stripped out if it's expired, which falls under "projection".  There are two ways projection happens in MongoDB, and I'm afraid neither is exactly what you want:

1. find() lets you project the fields to return, but that's limited to: 1 (do), 0 (don't), or a few special operators if the field is an array, which a subdocument is not.
2. Aggregation gives you a $project operator to transform the results, but doesn't let you disappear this field (subdocument) entirely: if it has an expiration date in the past, you can replace it with null or (probably better) an empty document, but that's as close as you can get.